# can't understand generator.throw() in coroutine

Tags: python-3.x

I'm reading the book 'fluent python' on coroutine chapter but can't understand some points,

generator.throw(exc_type[, exc_value[, traceback]])
Causes the yield expression where the generator was paused to raise the exception
given. If the exception is handled by the generator, flow advances to the next
yield , **and the value yielded becomes the value of the generator.throw call**. If the
exception is not handled by the generator, it propagates to the context of the caller.

can someone help me explain the text is bold?

```
class DemoException(Exception):
    """An exception type for the demonstration."""
def demo_exc_handling():
    print('-> coroutine started')
    while True:
        try:
            x = yield
        except DemoException:
            print('*** DemoException handled. Continuing...')
        else:
            print('-> coroutine received: {!r}'.format(x))
    raise RuntimeError('This line should never run.')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you've left off some code.

```
if __name__=="__main__":
    z = demo_exc_handling()
    print(z.__next__()) # arrives at yield
    x = z.throw(DemoException())
    print(x)
```

This means, z.throw() will cause the generator to handle the exception, continue the loop, and return the next value of the yield. If we modify the code to actually return a value we can see that.

```
def demo_exc_handling():
    print('-> coroutine started')
    i = 0
    while True:
        i += 1
        try:
            x = yield i
        except DemoException:
            print('*** DemoException handled. Continuing...')
        else:
            print('-> coroutine received: {!r}'.format(x))
    raise RuntimeError('This line should never run.')
```

When we run the first part, you should see

```
-> coroutine started
1
*** DemoException handled. Continuing...
2
```

The generator.throw was handled and the loop continued and 2 was returned because it is the next yield value.